# How do we grab the content from Toast UI Editor (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, toast-ui-editor

I'm sorry if this is blindingly simple, but I cannot for the life of me find some documentation on it.

I've been through http://nhnent.github.io/tui.editor/api/latest/index.html and couldn't see it. With most JavaScript wysiwyg editors, they usually dump the data into a `<textarea>`, but this one doesn't.

Just checking to see if anyone else has used it and knows how that works. I want to use it within a form and submit the data/text it generates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried: `var content = editor.getValue();` ?

Comment: That did it. You'd think that they would have that as an example in their getting started area - I guess I didn't dig deep enough in all their methods that were available.

Comment: In react: `editorRef.current.editorInst.getMarkdown()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `editor.getMarkdown()`;

This gets content to markdown

https://nhn.github.io/tui.editor/latest/ToastUIEditorCore

Answer (score 0):

I am using this

```
editor.getHTML()
```